# Rename Files in Folder Separately Using Excel VBA Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to rename the file names in folder path "C:\Users\rmaalouf\Desktop\Sample".

So, i have the files names in Column A, Advisors names in Column B, and Policy Numbers in Column C.

the below code should rename the file name in "A2" when i type "d" in "D2" to "B2"&"C2"&"A2".

I hope that i was clear enough. is there something wrong in the below code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer

xCellColumn = 4
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column

MyPath = "C:\Users\rmaalouf\Desktop\Sample\"
MyFile = Cells(xRow, 1).Value
NewName = Cells(xRow, 2).Value & " " & Cells(xRow, 3).Value & " " & Cells(xRow, 1).Value

    If Target.Text = "d" Then
        If xCol = xCellColumn Then
            If Dir(MyPath & MyFile) <> "" Then
                Name MyPath & MyFile As MyPath & NewName
            Else
            MsgBox "File not found"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you including the file extensions in this? They are needed for it to work.

Comment: i used "Name MyPath & MyFile As MyPath & NewName"  that will include the folder path. "Name As" worked well when i use it on the whole sheet as a macro. however, i can't get it to work on change.

Comment: I'm talking about the file extension not the folder. like .png or .xls etc. It needs those if you don't have them in it. I don't know cause you haven't said but it's something to look at cause I don't see anything immediately obviously wrong. I mean you don't have to add one but if the filename you're changing has one you need to use it.

Comment: You say _the below code should rename the file..._ and imply that it doesn't.   What does it do instead?  What are some example values in the specified cells?

Comment: You say _however, i can't get it to work on change_ .  Is your code in the relevant sheet module (not and regular modlue)?  Do you have `Application.EnableEvents` turned on?

Comment: @Simon, i put the original file name in the end of renaming to keep the file type as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. What I'm saying is if you're trying to rename say an image called `Photo1.PNG`. You need to use `Photo1.PNG` as your `MyFile` variable not `Photo1`. If you do then ok. I can't see what's in your cells so I don't know. Maybe add a picture of what's in the sheet so we can see what's in those cells.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, it doesn't take any action at all. it doesn't even give an error that i can fix.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, can you please clarify more about the `Application.EnableEvents`? i used the above code before and it worked well but not for renaming.

Comment: Ok.  Firstly,  does your code run at all?  Put a break point on it and change a cell.  Does the VBA stop at at the break point, or not run at all?

Comment: @Simon, i added a picture of the data i'm testing on.

Comment: Ok I tested it on my computer. Added 6 images into a folder, named all the same used same values as you. Used exact same code except folder location obviously. When I put a "d" in column D it worked fine.For example I got an output of `Roger 7m100000 1.PNG`. This would make me think that maybe your events are off like chris. Make a test sub and just put the line `Application.EnableEvents = True` and run it. Or open the immediate window and run that line.

Comment: @Simon that, or the code is not in the Sheet module

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/bJgpj6X/filerenamegif.gif . Showing you it does work. But yes as Chris said also you need to make sure it is in the sheet module that it is for.

Comment: Thank you guys. It's fixed Now. the code was not in the sheet module. Thank you very much

Comment: @roger glad you found it.  That makes this a typo question.   You might want to delete it yourself (to save others the bother)